# Grouping together two nested figures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have two Figures made of 4 `subfigure`s (2x2). They both look like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htb!]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.23]{figures/1.pdf}
            \caption{{subfigure 1}}    
            \label{fig:subfigure1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}  
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[scale=0.23]{figures/2.pdf}
            \caption{{subfigure 2}}     
            \label{fig:subfigure2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.23\textwidth}   
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[scale=0.23]{figures/3.pdf}
            \caption{{subfigure 3}}    
            \label{fig:subfigure3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \quad
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.23\textwidth}   
            \centering 
            \includegraphics[scale=0.23]{figures/4.pdf}
            \caption{{subfigure 4}}    
            \label{fig:subfigure4}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{first set of 4 subfigures.} 
        \label{fig:4subfigures_1}
    \end{figure}
```

Now, since the document is in a 2-column format, I would like one such group of 2x2 subfigures to appear next to the other one, preferably on top.

What's an easy way to group them together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be like this?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-4]
  \begin{figure*}[htb!]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{{subfigure 1}}
            \label{fig:subfigure1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{{subfigure 2}}
            \label{fig:subfigure2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{{subfigure 3}}
            \label{fig:subfigure3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{{subfigure 4}}
            \label{fig:subfigure4}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{first set of 4 subfigures.}
        \label{fig:4subfigures_1}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \caption{{subfigure 1}}
            \label{fig:subfigure1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{{subfigure 2}}
            \label{fig:subfigure2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{{subfigure 3}}
            \label{fig:subfigure3}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{{subfigure 4}}
            \label{fig:subfigure4}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{first set of 4 subfigures.}
        \label{fig:4subfigures_1}
  \end{minipage}
    \end{figure*}
    \kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]